# Eclipse plugin development: Deliver tools (e.g. compiler)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am going to change the title of this thread as soon as I find a better one..

What I am about to write is a plugin for Eclipse that allows one to create a new project for a specific microcontroller (it's not important which one).

I want this plugin to deliver some tools right on e.g. I want to configure the builder as such that all C files are compiled with [SDCC](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/).

Regarding to this project I would like to know

- **How can I provide e.g. the SDCC compiler included inside my plugin?**
- Are there any good tutorials that show how to do that?
- Are there recommended libraries I should take a look at for plugin dev?
- Are there any tutorials that show how to configure a plugin such that there is a standard running configurateion available (such that e.g. the project is built automatically and can be run by clicking the runner button)

I am new to Eclipse plugin development so any further links to general tutorials regarding to that matter are welcome.

I already found [www.eclipsepluginsite.com](http://eclipsepluginsite.com/) which was a great help so far.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I provide e.g. the SDCC compiler included inside my plugin?

You don't.  You ask the user to provide you a link to the SDCC compiler.

> Are there recommended libraries I should take a look at for plugin development?

agad already [pointed you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17675250/300257) to the Vogella tutorials.  I've used this book, [Eclipse Plug-Ins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321553462), to learn Eclipse plug-in development.

> Are there any tutorials that show how to configure a plugin such that there is a standard running configuration available (such that e.g. the project is built automatically and can be run by clicking the runner button)

You can take a look at the Eclipse class ImportOperation.  It's found in the org.eclipse.ui.ide.source jar.  Source jars are included with Eclipse RCP.  This class does the actual work of copying objects from the local file system into the Eclipse workspace.

I tried to attach the source code, but an answer can only be 30,000 characters or less.

Comment: Hi and thank you for answering. What if I want to provide the SDCC with my plugin? I want my plugin to provide it and configure the PATH so there is no need to care about installing additional tools to use this plugin. I'm going to look at Vogellas tutorials - it looks promising. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best tutorials are on [Vogella site](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html). I found there nearly all information I needed, when I developed Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to take a look at this.